# Constant 12 hour countdown with moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to make a countdown using moment.js and jQuery. It's supposed to countdown to 12.00, and when it has passed 12.00, it should count down to 24.00 etc. So always count down the next 12 hours. It also has to be in UTC. This is what I have right now and it works fine, except when it has passed 12.00, it says "Timer done".

How can I achieve this in the best way?

```
 var currentTime, endTime, timeDif;

currentTime = moment.now().format('X');
endTime = moment(moment.utc(12, "HH")).format('X');

function roundEndTimer() {

    var Hours, Minutes, Seconds;

    timeDif = endTime - currentTime;

    function updateTime (){
        Seconds = timeDif;

        Hours = Math.floor(Seconds/3600);
        Seconds -= Hours * 3600;

        Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds/60);
        Seconds -= Minutes * 60;


    }
    function tick (){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        updateTime();
        displayTime();

        if(timeDif > 0) {

            timeDif - 1;
            timer = setTimeout(tick, 1*1000)
        }else {

            $("#roundendtime").html("Timer done");
        }
    }

    function displayTime() {
        var out;
        out = moment().hours(Hours).format('HH')+':'+moment().minutes(Minutes).format('mm')+':'+moment().seconds(Seconds).format('ss');
        $("#roundendtime").html(out);
    }

    var timer = setTimeout(tick, 1*1000);
}
```

Comment: you'll probably want to use something like `setInterval(resetEndTime, 1000*60*60*12)`

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use it

Comment: `resetEndTime` would be a function that sets a variable to the next end time (either the next 12:00 or the next 00:00), `setInterval`  is a built in javascript function that means "run <the first argument> every <the second argument> milliseconds". your tick function would compare current time to the next end time